# Get the column names from file in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to spark/scala. I have a file say config where I specify all the column names.

Config:

```
Id,
Emp_Name,
Dept,
Address,
Account
```

I have a dataframe where i select the column names like:

```
df.select("id","Emp_Name","Dept","Address","Account").show()
```

Instead of specifying the column names in select, I want to get the column names from config file like

```
df.select(config-file_column_names).show()
```

Comment: In case, you need to select only some columns, then you have to pass them as parameters in your driver program as the driver is the one where you trigger your spark query. In case you wan to choose all the columns of the file, then you can go ahead as @philantrovert mentioned....

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the commas in your file if each column is in a different line.

This is the definition of `select` :

```
def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame
def select(cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*): DataFrame
```

We are going to use the second definition here.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val colNames = sc.textFile("file").map(_.replaceAll(",", "") ).map(col(_)).collect

// Unpacking the array in `select`

df.select(colNames: _*).show
```